# WordPress. Add styles/class to make button in an admin menu disabled (inactive)

Tags: javascript, html, css, wordpress, custom-post-type

[Here's what I have atm](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cR47U.png)

I've added a button for my custom post type that supposed to allow bulk upload posts using CSV.

Here's the JS code I used for this (I found this code on StackOverflow and it seem to be working well):

```
function add_button () {
    $($(".wrap .page-title-action")[0])
        .after('<button id="sh_import_csv_button" class="page-title-action">Import CSV</button><input id="csv_upload" type="file" hidden/>');
}
```

When I add "disabled" property to the button - it works, but button still looks like active, so it may confuse users. I need to make it disabled during CSV processing time.

The question is, is there some default WP CSS class or at least set of CSS styles to make it look properly?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, there is no default style for the `page-title-action` class name when its element also has `disabled` attribute. But you can add your own style as well. If I want a button in a ui look disabled I usually play with the opacity. And very often thats enough. So what about adding

```
.page-title-action[disabled] {
    opacity: 0.5;
}
```

to an admin css...

Also I would rewrite your snippet like this:

```
var add_button = function () {
    $(".wrap .page-title-action").first().after(
        '<button id="sh_import_csv_button" class="page-title-action">' +
        'Import CSV</button><input id="csv_upload" type="file" hidden/>'
    );
}
```

If you also need advice on how to add the css just tell me in a comment...

Comment: Thanks for your advice and remark concerning the code I provided. I did it little bit different so there is no need to add such style. But, as for me, it's kind of weird why WP doesn't have predefined class for so typical case when you need to make a button disabled :(

Comment: Search in WP for the `[disabled]`-selector. If I do so I get 113 hits (a lot of double counts for ".min" and non-".min" versions but there is styling going on for the `[disabled]`-selector). The `.page-title-action[disabled]`-selector is not in the code base for a simple reason: There is no use case in WP core!